# karate : Send boolean values as parameters in request JSON

Tags: json, karate

```
* def updategetPhonePref = !getPhonePref
* def mpRequestJson =
            """
            {
                "entity": '<entity>',
                "consent": {
                    "PHONE": updategetPhonePref
                },
                "notices": [{
                    "title": "policy",
                    "version": "NA"
                }],
                "source": "existing web"
            }
            """
            Given path '<entity>'
            And request mpRequestJson
            When method PUT
            Then status 200
            Examples:
                |entity  |
                |abc     |
```

I have the above request JSON and the value of updategetPhonePref is Boolean. How do I pass it as a parameter into request JSON parameter "PHONE"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [embedded expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions),

```
"PHONE": "#(updategetPhonePref)"
```